# Social Network Dataset

Tags: twitter, dataset, facebook-like, social-networking, mining

I'm working on Social Network mining project, and I'm looking for a "real social network dataset" (comments, ,comments on comment, likes, friendship, interest, feeling, places,liked pages, published photos, videos, posts, hashtags anything more is positive )

I searched a lot, but all available networks are just about nodes and edges (like A follow B). For example

http://snap.stanford.edu/
I search twitter, but its not open because of privacy terms
http://an.kaist.ac.kr/traces/WWW2010.html

Anyone have a suggestion for a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial
step by step how to stream twitter to hadoop
https://github.com/DataDanSandler/YouTubeREADME#video-5-configure-flume